# ajax get content of another site and use selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have this ajax call

```
  var content = $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                async: false
            }).responseText;
```

This response is plain html of ajax.php site.

I want to use selector on this response `content`
Example:

```
$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: By 'another site' do you mean that it's on a different domain to your own? If so, this will not work as you will be blocked by the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Yeah, I wasn't sure if that was just language difficulty, given the example is clearly same-origin. (Or of course, there could be a CORS relationship...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder very true, although CORS support seems very sparse at the moment :(

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Well, all modern browsers have it (you have to jump through hoops for IE8 and 9 -- a decision from the Microsoft, and separately the jQuery team [not working around it like all the other browser differences] that I Just Don't Understand -- but it's there). I think it's fairly understandable that there are very few sites that enable it by default...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery to parse the HTML, then query it (all without adding it to the document):

```
var elements = $(content);
elements.find("li").each(/*...*/);
```

---

<s>Side note:</s>

If by "another site" you mean another website rather than the `ajax.php` example you've given, note that the call will probably be blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). That is, unless the other site grants your requesting page access via [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (and you're using a browser that [supports CORS properly](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors), rather than IE8 or IE9 which have support but non-standard and not enabled in jQuery, or IE7 or earlier that don't have it at all). *(You've said in a comment below you mean another page on your site, so this doesn't apply.)*

---

Side note #2: If you're using jQuery's `$.ajax`, you wouldn't normally want to go directly to `responseText`. Instead:

```
var content;
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        content = data;
    }
});
```

---

Side note #3: `async: false` is almost universally a Bad Idea<sup>(tm)</sup>, and it will be removed from jQuery before too much longer. Embrace asynchronicity.

Comment: Not "another site" i mean another page.